# How to close a popup window in javascript that was sent to the background

Tags: javascript, html

So I was trying to use the `window.close` method, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's the code:

```
    <script>
        var popup;
        function openPandora() {
            popup = window.open('http://www.pandora.com', '', 'width=100, height=100, resizable=no');
            popup.blur();
            document.getElementById('container').focus();
        }
        function closeWindow() {
            popup.close();
        }

    </script>
```

The HTML just calls `<a>` with an `onClick="closeWindow();"`

Any ideas on how to get that popup to close? Thanks!

Comment: Use `window.popup`, instead of just `popup`.

Comment: @alex yeah just checked ..thr4 deleted :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code ---

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>For Alex</title>
<script>
        var popup;
        function openPandora() {
            popup = window.open('http://www.pandora.com', '', 'width=100, height=100, resizable=no');
            popup.blur();
            document.getElementById('container').focus();
        }
        function closeWindow() {
            popup.close();
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="add-friend" onClick="openPandora()">Add Friend</button>
<ul id="friends-list">
</ul>
<a href="javascript:closeWindow()">dfd</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although  div container is null, and code is very badly written ..but its working ;)

Comment: @alex hahahaha edited code from my backbone tut file, so the title is this ;)

Comment: @swapnesh what's the difference between your code and mine. I'm confused why mine doesn't work. I tried href="javascript:closeWindow()" and it didn't work.

Comment: @Vikram If you have a firebug installed check the JS errors im sure u have have something more code on your file..and let us know so that we can help u :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure if closeWindow() is getting called.

Try this

```
function closeWindow() {
   alert("Going to close popup");
   alert(popup);
   popup.close();
  }
```

What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working for me with your code.

Try here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zfSWX/